# Microsoft Store on Windows Server 2019

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2019

I am trying out the g4dn.xlarge EC2 instance on AWS running windows server 2019 and my main aim was to use the server for gaming using [xbox game pass](https://www.xbox.com/en-IN/xbox-game-pass), but I couldn't find the windows store on it. I tried many methods given on various sites. I don't want to get the store using developer mode.
Is there any other way to get it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Search for a file called 'WindowsStore_LTSC2019.exe'. Although I still cannot download new app from it, it could update existing app I have installed with https://store.rg-adguard.net/

Comment: By the way, it worked perfectly for Win10LTSC. It just cannot install new app on WindowsServer

Comment: Deailed instructions with step by step screenshots https://windowsreport.com/download-microsoft-store-apps-without-store/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this scripts that installs Store, Xbox Identity and more on your EC2 Instance. Remember first unzip and run Add-Store.cmd as administrator:
https://github.com/kkkgo/LTSC-Add-MicrosoftStore

Comment: Hey @Danurigom! Thank you for sharing this. However, this was for a commercial purpose and we cannot run third-party scripts there.